# Can't omit _id field in findOneAndUpdate operation

Tags: typescript, mongodb, mongoose, typegoose

I have a function for updating mongoDB documents. After making manipulations to the sent data, I update wanted document using mongoose's `findOneAndUpdate` function. Since I'll be using saved data I've set `new:true` and use object named `userReturnFormat` as projection to retrieve necessary fields. Code example:

```js
const userReturnFormat = {
    email: 1,
    name: 1,
    surname: 1,
    _id: 0
}

const updatedUser = (await UserModel.findOneAndUpdate(
            { registerId: params.user.registerId },
            { $set: data },
            { new: true, projection: userReturnFormat }
        )) as User
```

As you can see from `userReturnFormat` object `_id` field is marked as `false`. When I use `{_id:0}` as the projection it successfully omits `_id` field. I've tried directly writing projection inside update operation but it still returns `_id` field when I mark any property as `true`. I can use delete operand to remove `_id` field after updating document but I don't want to use this since projection should be able to be used for this purpose.

`{_id: 0 }` as projection:

```js
const updatedUser = (await UserModel.findOneAndUpdate(
            { registerId: params.user.registerId },
            { $set: data },
            { new: true, projection: { _id: 0 } }
        )) as User
```

RESULT:

```js
{
  email: ‘j_doe@example.com’,
  password: ‘HASHED_PASSWORD’,
  name: ‘JOHN’,
  surname: ‘DOE’,
  type: ‘example’,
  createdAt: 2024-01-03T12:57:20.972Z,
  updatedAt: 2024-01-04T07:30:27.153Z
}
```

Using `delete` operand:

```js
const updatedUser = (
            await UserModel.findOneAndUpdate({ registerId: params.user.registerId }, { $set: data }, { new: true, projection: userReturnFormat })
        )?._doc

delete updatedUser._id
```

RESULT:

```js
{
  email: ‘j_doe@example.com’,
  name: ‘JOHN’,
  surname: ‘DOE’,
}
```

Comment: The `_id` field is always returned as default and must be explicitly excluded as per the [docs](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/reference/method/db.collection.findOneAndUpdate/#_id-field-projection). Mongoose has a `select: false` option that you can add to the schema definition for a specific property but the `_id` property is pretty important to MongoDB so would only recommend that option for things like passwords etc to stop accidental data exposure.

Comment: As it can be seen from userReturnFormat object, _id field is marked as excluded. I'll be exposing updated data to public so I don't want to expose _id field in returned data.

Comment: Looks like a bug. What exact version of mongoose, nodejs native driver, and the DB itself is it?  I'd like to reproduce.

Comment: @AlexBlex MongoDB: v7.0.0 - NodeJS: v20.8.0 - I'm using Typegoose 12.0.0 which should be using Mongoose 8.0.3

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try with `select`:

```
await UserModel.findOneAndUpdate(
   { registerId: params.user.registerId },
   { $set: data },
   { new: true }
).select(userReturnFormat).exec();
```